# Mongoose queries to return promises

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose to connect to MongoDB. It says here "Mongoose queries are not promises. If you need a fully-fledged promise, use the .exec() function."

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

```
var promise = models.Trends.find({ 'name': 'test' }).where('bdate').gt(timeObj).exec();
console.log(promise instanceof Promise);
```

This still outputs false. BTW the promise library I am using is 'q'.

Comment: *"this still outputs false. **BTW the promise library i am using is 'q'**."* i mean.... If you told mongoose to use q, and you're asking if the promise returned is an instance of a native promise... the result seems like it'd be accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line at top to enable promise support for mongoose.

```
mongoose.Promise = Promise
```

Comment: I understand i was using q but checking if its instanceof of native promise. Changing to use native promises fixed it!